# How can a Windows Store desktop bridge app properly deal with it's conventional counterpart?

Tags: desktop-bridge

I have a typical WPF application that I want to add to the Windows Store. I want to retain the conventional installation method for versions of Windows earlier than Windows 10. My app is only intended to run in a single instance, and manages that using a class written by Microsoft (http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/SingleInstance.cs.txt). This class does not seem to work correctly with the appx package, though.

What steps can I and should I take to safeguard a user that has mistakenly installed conventionally AND got the app from the Windows Store?

Answer (score 0):

With the release of the Creators Update, Microsoft published [this detailed blog post](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/03/31/desktop-bridge-creators-update/#rz71IKOmHgLWeYP0.97) with instructions on how to handle your situation, including data migration and others...

Our team, at [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/uwp-app-package.html) (*disclaimer: where I work*), has developed built-in support to handle such situation with just a few click, so you don't have write any code. Check out the video demo below:

- [User and Data migration for Desktop Bridge apps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V3xqJ5l0HpY) - also uninstalling the desktop version of the application, when installing the store version